# Can a disabled form element share a column with an enabled form element?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, insert

Can a disabled form element share a column with an enabled form element?

I have a form which has 4 sets of comboboxes which are populated with data from another table and are only visible and active when certain selections are made, each set of coboboxes contains 4 possible option sets with either one or none visible and active at one time, I have set each set of comboboxes to save to the same table column because there will only ever be one that is working at any time so 4 seperate columns for each set of options would be too complicated when filtering data (in my mind at least).

The problem that I am having is that I am getting a blank value saved to the database table instead of the selected value, I have place the coding below to help explain what I am trying to do.

Form coding
visible/active options

```
<select name="Lab1" id="Lab1" style="visibility:hidden;" onChange="if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp1'].disabled=false}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp2'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp2'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp3'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp3'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp4'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['Samp4'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['SegmCol1'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='Alpha Bio Labs'){this.form['SegmCol1'].disabled=false}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['Samp1'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['Samp2'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['Samp2'].disabled=false}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['Samp3'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['Samp3'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['Samp4'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['Samp4'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['SegmCol1'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='Cellmark'){this.form['SegmCol1'].disabled=false}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['Samp1'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['Samp2'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['Samp2'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['Samp3'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['Samp3'].disabled=false}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['Samp4'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['Samp4'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['SegmCol1'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='DNA Legal'){this.form['SegmCol1'].disabled=false}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['Samp1'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['Samp2'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['Samp2'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['Samp3'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['Samp3'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['Samp4'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['Samp4'].disabled=false}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['SegmCol1'].style.visibility='visible'}
              if (this.value=='The Doctors Lab'){this.form['SegmCol1'].disabled=false}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['Samp1'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['Samp1'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['Samp2'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['Samp2'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['Samp3'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['Samp3'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['Samp4'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['Samp4'].disabled=true}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['SegmCol1'].style.visibility='hidden'}
              if (this.value=='Lab'){this.form['SegmCol1'].disabled=true};">
                <option selected>Lab</option>
                <option value="Alpha Bio Labs">Alpha Bio Labs</option>
                <option value="Cellmark">Cellmark</option>
                <option value="DNA Legal">DNA Legal</option>
                <option value="The Doctors Lab">The Doctors Lab</option>
              </select>
```

Selection that will be saved to the database

```
 <option selected >Select Sample Type</option>
                <?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("", "", "", "");

$results = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT SampleType, LabFee, LabFeeExtra FROM `sampletypes` WHERE Lab = 'Alpha Bio Labs'");

mysqli_close($connection); 
foreach($results as $user): ?>
                <option value="<?= $user['SampleType']; ?>">
                <?= $user['SampleType']; ?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
              </select>
```

php coding to save to the database

```
$LaborDept = $_POST['Lab1'];
$SampleType1 = $_POST['Samp1'];
$SampleType1 = $_POST['Samp2'];
$SampleType1 = $_POST['Samp3'];
$SampleType1 = $_POST['Samp4'];
$Segmented1 = $_POST['SegmCol1'];
$LaborDept2 = $_POST['Lab2'];
$SampleType2 = $_POST['Samp5'];
$SampleType2 = $_POST['Samp6'];
$SampleType2 = $_POST['Samp7'];
$SampleType2 = $_POST['Samp8'];
$Segmented2 = $_POST['SegmCol2'];
$LaborDept3 = $_POST['Lab3'];
$SampleType3 = $_POST['Samp9'];
$SampleType3 = $_POST['Samp10'];
$SampleType3 = $_POST['Samp11'];
$SampleType3 = $_POST['Samp12'];
$Segmented3 = $_POST['SegmCol3'];
$LaborDept4 = $_POST['Lab4'];
$SampleType4 = $_POST['Samp13'];
$SampleType4 = $_POST['Samp14'];
$SampleType4 = $_POST['Samp15'];
$SampleType4 = $_POST['Samp16'];
$SegmentedCollection = $_POST['SegmCol'];
$Decleration = $_POST['Decl'];

mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `collectsamp`(`SampleID`, `LaborDept`, `NumberofSamples`, `SampleType1`, `Segmented1`, `LaborDept2`, `SampleType2`, `Segmented2`, `LaborDept3`, `SampleType3`, `Segmented3`, `LaborDept4`, `SampleType4`, `SegmentedCollection`, `Decleration`) VALUES ('$LabID', '$LaborDept', '$NumberofSamples', '$SampleType1', '$Segmented1', '$LaborDept2', '$SampleType2', '$Segmented2', '$LaborDept3', '$SampleType3', '$Segmented3', '$LaborDept4', '$SampleType4', '$SegmentedCollection', '$Decleration')");
```

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by remaking the comboboxes and tweaking the coding to match the snippet below;

```
$SampleType4 = $_POST['Samp13'] . " " . $_POST['Samp14'] . " " . $_POST['Samp15'] . " " . $_POST['Samp16'];
```